# Bruvac: Specifying Mill

Tags: magic-the-gathering

With the new card Bruvac, the Grandiloquent, and the reformatting of mill as a keyword, I have a couple questions.

It specifically defines "if an opponent would **mill** one or more cards." Are they errataing things such as [Tome Scour](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTome%20Scour%5d), which is clearly "mill?"

In the case that they are errataing, what about cards that are a little more unclear? For example, [Tunnel Vision](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTunnel%20Vision%5d) reads "If it is, that player puts the rest of the revealed cards into his graveyard." Because this does not directly read "puts the top N cards of their library into their graveyard," does that mean this is not "mill," and won't be affected by Bruvac?

Comment: We don't know because they haven't announced the erratas yet. Before they do, any answers will just be speculation, and after they do, you can just read the card.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case, thanks for clarifying

Comment: Agree with murgatroid. As for speculation, I expect Tome Scour and other clear cases to get errata, while cards like Tunnel Vision will not. While both cards technically put a number of the top lib cards into the gy, Tunnel Vision lets you look at them first, unlike a classic mill. Tunnel Vision will also not trigger Bruvac, only cards that actually use the mill keyword do.

Comment: I'll just have to stick with the Persistent Petitioners plan then (reasonably sure that'll get errataed)

Comment: This doesn't definitely answer the question, but the release notes for Bruvac do say "If a player is instructed to put a card into their graveyard without using the word 'mill,' Bruvac's ability doesn't apply." and "As a rule of thumb, if an effect instructs a player to look at or reveal a card before it's put into its owner's graveyard, it's unlikely to have received errata."

Comment: We know that Thought Scour is receiving errata, and it would be very strange for them to errata some old cards with the new wording without doing it to all old cards (obviously excluding those for which the new wording would be functionally different in any way).

Comment: The card says on it "To mil a card, a player puts the top card of their library into the graveyard". That to me makes it look like they are defining the act of moving a card from the top of the library as milling. But as others have said we will have to wait until more information is provided.

Comment: It's definitely a keyword action. They have announced that much. And the release notes I quoted make it pretty clear that many but not all of the cards that instruct you to put cards from the top of your library into your graveyard will have errata to use that keyword. The reminder text does not imply that every instance of "put N top cards of your library into your graveyard" is mill. It's like how the reminder text for draw can be "To draw a card, a player puts the top card of their library into their hand", but not every instance of moving cards that way is "draw".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a planned errata to introduce the “mill” keyword to earlier cards.

You can already see it in [eleven mill cards reprinted in Jumpstart](https://scryfall.com/search?q=e%3Ajmp+is%3Areprint+o%3Aput+o%3Atop+o%3Alibrary+o%3Agraveyard+-sinprodder). For example [Thought Scour](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThought%20Scour%5d)'s Jumpstart print says “Target player mills two cards”; it used to say “Target player puts the top two cards of their library into their graveyard”. [Tome Scour](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTome%20Scour%5d) uses the same template as Thought Scour except it says “five” instead of “two”, so it will assuredly receive errata to say “Target player mills five cards.”

Eli Shiffrin, the rules manager, tweeted guidelines about [what to expect with the new mill errata](https://twitter.com/EliShffrn/status/1274132022743625728) and says it should arrive in Gatherer on Tuesday (meaning the 23rd of June):

> Handy rule of thumb on the upcoming "mill" errata (in Gatherer Tuesday): If you look at the cards and then move those specific cards to the yard, it's not "mill." If you move cards and then look at them (or don't look at them at all), it's probably "mill." #WotCStaff

He [confirms as an example](https://twitter.com/EliShffrn/status/1274140539856674818) that [Mind Funeral](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMind%20Funeral%5d) will not say “mill” but [Traumatize](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTraumatize%5d) will. This makes it fairly clear [Tunnel Vision](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTunnel%20Vision%5d) *will not* receive errata to say “mill”.

Comment: It looks like the errata is now in Gatherer, so this answer doesn't need to guess anymore: Traumatize has errata to say "mill", and Tunnel Vision does not.